# Set Background color to div tag dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and trying to set the background color of a div tag in react application. The following code basically gives a different background color when rendered for the following div tag. I am unable to set the value using the following syntax.

```
         let month= ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
         let temp;
         let c = '#d8ef8a !important';

         temp = month.indexOf(this.props.label);
       //  console.log(temp);
         if(temp <= 2)
          c = c;
          else if (temp > 2 && temp <= 5)
          c = '#d8ef8a !important';
          else if (temp > 5 && temp <= 8)
          c = '#ffa77b !important';
          else if(temp > 8)
          c = '#d9bdf6 !important';
          else
          c = '#000 !important';
        // console.log(color);
        return (
            <div  style={{ display: 'flex',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:c, borderLeft:'solid 1px white',position:'absolute',height:20,left:this.props.left,width:this.props.width}}>
                <div>
                {this.props.label}
                </div>
            </div>)
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow! :) Would it be possible to share any errors you get? It's always easier to debug it like that. Also, it's pretty helpful if you tell us your expected and actual behavior.

Comment: I never got any errors for the above line. React framework was not rendering the background style attribute to the browser. When a color was assigned inline, All was working fine.However, the background color was not rendered to the browser when i tried dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things in this code here. First you dont need the color **c** variable to itself if it is less than 2 and second you dont need **important!** for color as it only take one color at a time.

```
temp = month.indexOf("September");
  //Removed extra condition and important statement
  if (temp > 2 && temp <= 5) c = "#d8ef8a ";
  else if (temp > 5 && temp <= 8) c = "#ffa77b ";
  else if (temp > 8) c = "#d9bdf6 ";
  else c = "#000 ";
```

Here is working code : https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-babbage-mcdlf

Comment: damn it mate, you beat me to it!

Comment: @spgk if it works make sure you upvote the answer and marked as accepted so that when other developers find the same problem. They can easily find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that removing `!important` did the trick.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-thunder-nkbnn